# Where is the "Free on iTunes" link?

Tags: ios, itunes, itunes-store

Is "Free on iTunes" gone again?
I'm unable to find the "Free on iTunes" link from the iOS app. I have seen no announcements nor news that "Free on iTunes" was going to be removed. How do I locate this link (if it's still available)?

Comment: In which app are you looking for this link?

Comment: The latest version of iTunes to date, iTunes iOS 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an iPhone, you're right it's currently missing even on 8.3. Perhaps an oversight. On iPad, it's ok. Open up the iTunes Store, it's in the footer for Music:

[image]

Comment: The iPad seems like the oversight as the link has also been removed from the desktop iTunes store. Seems like Apple is quietly removing free content.